# Running nodejs program from PHP exec vs http

Tags: php, node.js

I would want to run a nodejs program from PHP. What would be the fastest way to do it when you compare these options:

- Run the nodejs code as a webservice and call via a http URL
- Run via exec and grab the output

Edit:
The nodejs code will run a headless browser (casperjs/phantomjs) and it will render a page with canvas data and then submit the canvas image to a service.

Comment: If by "nodejs code" you mean the nodejs server, then the answer depends on two things: overhead of spawning the huge nodejs process versus network latency for the http request.

Answer (score 0):

That depends a lot on the nodejs application itself, if the initialization is relatively heavy, and it can already be pre-initialized as a webservice then that is probably a bit quicker.

Otherwise, if it is very simple an exec is probably quicker since you're skipping the whole http part

Comment: I have edited the original question to give some more info. Could you please have a look?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the node code will already making an external network call which would be orders of magnitude slower than a local network call so in terms of performance there should not be much difference.

Of course if performance is an important requirement you should measure both approaches and select the best for your case.

If you have a requirement to be able to invoke this process from a different application then the http endpoint would be better provided security measures are properly implemented as an endpoint would potentially increase your attack surface.